# mysql command line unable to understand how to login

Tags: mysql, command-line

I installed mysql 5.6 on windows 7(32 bit). When I open command line client 5.6 it asks me for password i put password (mysql) and press enter, it gives connection id number, meaning connection was successful.

I created a database by the name bank

```
create database bank;
```

it was created.

I created the lrngsql database user with full privileges on the bank database using following command

```
Grant all privileges on bank.* to 'lrngsql'@'localhost' identified by 'xyz';
```

It was successful too.
Now here my query begins, how do i login to this user (lrngsql).
the command i m typing in prompt

```
mysql>use bank;
```

it says

> Database changed.

then i type following command to login to lrngsql

```
mysql -u lrngsql -p xyz;
```

but it gives me error. please help me what should i exactly type in order to get in to lrngsql user on bank database.

Comment: there should not be any space in between -p and your password

Comment: I suppose [reading the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) would be completely out of the question!

Comment: i m trying to learn mysql using MYSQL Reference downloaded from developers website. it gives a command line statement to use which is: mysql -h host -u username -p; i type: mysql localhost -u lrngsql -pxyz; it gives me syntax error. i type: mysql -u lrngsql -pxyz; still syntax error. i type: mysql -u lrngsql and press enter it gives a prompt -> meaning it's waiting for the semicolon but does not prompt for password. that's what is confusing me. please help me what mistake am i doing? thank you.

Comment: i also tried: mysql -u lrangsql@localhost -pxyz but still same error

Comment: also, i m using mysql version 5.6.24, is there any different syntax for this version?

Comment: is it even possible to login as another user except root using command line client?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u lrngsql -p xyz;
```

There should be minor change to command you have used for loggin in, there should not be any space in between -p and your password.

Like

```
mysql -u lrngsql -pxyz;
```

Comment: Or don't submit the password on the commandline (recommended) and wait for MySQL to prompt you.

Comment: i used mysql -u lrngsql -pxyz; but it gives me syntax error i used mysql -u lrngsql and pressed enter and it gives me this prompt -> meaning it's waiting for a semicolon and does not prompt for password. what mistake am i doing? please help me i m unable to proceed with my study

Comment: Have you already logged in to the server?? It won't wait for your semicolon btw. You have to run this command in the shell directly.